# CommonsMultipartResolver setMaxUploadSize limits the file size or the request size?

Tags: spring, upload, multipart, apache-commons-fileupload

I have an issue understanding the setMaxUploadSize method. I thought it is supposed to limit the file size. However, if I set the maxUploadSize to 10 bytes, just for testing purpose and then I upload a 10bytes file, the file is rejected and a MaxUploadSizeExceededException is thrown.

Looking in the code for commons-fileupload I understand that it first tests the Content-Length header. Since the Content-Lenght is 224 in my case, the upload is rejected.

So my question is: is the request body size limited or the size of the actual file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CommonsMultipartResolver is MultipartResolver implementation for Jakarta Commons DiskFileUpload. DiskFileUpload has 2 fields:
1) sizeMax - maximum allowed size of a complete request.
2) fileSizeMax - maximum allowed size of a single uploaded file.

CommonsMultipartResolver implements maxUploadSize field as:

```
    public void setMaxUploadSize(long maxUploadSize) {
    this.fileUpload.setSizeMax(maxUploadSize);
}
```

which explains the reason for your exception.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I understood from source code as well. I was confused because in Spring docs there is the following specification: `<!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>` http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html